# Render a block of a "parent" template from a "child" template in Twig

Tags: php, templates, twig

I have two templates:

***Fields.html.twig***, which includes a child template.

```
{% block important %}
  This block should be renderable from the sub template
{% endblock important %}

{% include 'XButton.html.twig' %}
```

***XButton.html.twig***, which needs to render blocks defined in the template that includes it.

```
block('important')
```

It seems like an included template isn't able to simply render blocks of whoever included it.
How can the parent template pass the full context to the child, so that the child can access the blocks defined in the parent?

Comment: Included files can't alter the content of their caller. All variables are also passed by value and not by reference

Comment: In other words: What I need is a "just copy the content of template x to this position". I thought include does this, but it seems like it doesn't know the blocks after being included.

Comment: what you're trying to do it's not possible - if you post (a simplified version of) the code of your templates we may be able to suggest a different approach to achieve what you're trying to do - which is a bit unclear atm...

Comment: Alright, I added a codepiece

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do it's impossible, because the included template has no way to know about blocks defined in other templates...

You'll need to structure your code a bit differently, so that the contents of the block are defined in the parent somehow - you have at least a couple of options:

#### Using [`set`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/set.html) and [`include`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/include.html): https://twigfiddle.com/l536np

*Fields.html.twig*

```
{% set important %}
    You define the child content as a variable in the parent...
{% endset %}

{% include 'XButton.html.twig' %}
```

*XButton.html.twig*

```
{{ important }}
```

#### Using [`embed`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/embed.html): https://twigfiddle.com/y9pp6p

*Fields.html.twig*

```
{% embed 'XButton.html.twig' %}
    {% block important %}
        You define the block content in the parent...
    {% endblock %}
{% endembed %}
```

*XButton.html.twig*

```
{{ block('important') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with include by passing the parent template name

```
{% block important %}
  This block should be renderable from the sub template
{% endblock important %}

{% include 'XButton.html.twig' with {'parent': _self} %}
```

And then use it in the include template

```
{{ block('important', parent) }}
```

Although this way the content of the block will be rendered twice - once when you define it in the parent, and once again in the child - see https://twigfiddle.com/6t0l6p

Comment: In your 1st code snippet you need to define the `block important` and it's content as well as adding that `include`, so you'll end up rendering the content of the block twice, won't you? See it in action here https://twigfiddle.com/6t0l6p

Comment: yes we obviously still need the `block important` on the parent template, I am just referring to the include statement on my example above. It just another option if you still want to use the `block`

Comment: fair enough - I added that info to your answer, and removed the downvote